# Content query web part

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part

I'm using SharePoint 2007.

I need to use "Content Query Web Part".
This web part displays a link to the item, I need the content type to show me all the rows (item).
**Is that possible?**

I do not want to use List View Web Part because it's not dynamically change (if I add column in the "list view" I need to refresh the "list view web part").

I do not found the "fields to display" in CQPW.
this is how it's look: [image]

Comment: Can you clarify more about what you need to show?

Comment: This really needs more detail

Comment: In one list I have 15 views. Those views are change all the time (the view manager delete\remove\add column).  I need to display all those view in web part page and I need that those view will change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You better use the List View Web Part to show all the Columns of a List.
If you still want to show some more Fields in the CQWP, you can add some Fields in the Webpart Settings (The amount of fields is different on each CQWP Template)

[image: CQWP Settings]

Comment: Hi! I do not want to use List View Web Part because it's not dynamically change (if I add column in the "list view" I need to refresh the "list view web part"). I try to add some field in the CQWP but I do not find the "Fields to display".

Comment: what URL Path I need to enter in the field "Field to display" "Link" ???

Answer (score 1):

"Fields to display" is a SharePoint 2010 feature. To display fields in SharePoint 2007 - following these [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb850574%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easiest way it to create your own web part, you will specify following things:

1. List to work with (web if not only current required)
2. View to work with

After you can get a view of the list and use it's method RenderAsHtml() to render html. Thus you will always get all changes made to view once they are made.

Please see examples of approach implementation: http://trentacular.com/2009/08/sharepoint-enhanced-list-view-web-part/
or http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5784